# Es6 TypeScript Proxy get как узнать что ссылка ведет на функцию?"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Хочу сделать универсальный прокси к .Net классам в том числе используя класс Proxy.
Но трудность в том, что не могу понять когда вызывается как метод, а когда через свойство

Например нужно обратиться например через http к сервису. Передать key, имя метода,параметры и получить ответ в виде key, и результата

Но выглядеть это будет так

```
let res = await this.counter.proxy.AllHello1("Всем Привет");
```

Вся сериализация будет происходит в Proxy get, а десериализация в событии в который будут передаваться key, и результат

Для свойства нужно вернуть Promise
 А для Метода нужно вернуть функцию создающую Promise

```
class CounterComponent {
    public currentCount: any;
    public dictionary = {};
    public proxy: any;
    constructor() { this.SetProxy(); }

    private GetPromise(name: PropertyKey,args)
    {

        let key = Guid.newGuid();
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let item = new Item(resolve, args, name);
            this.dictionary[key] = item;

        });


        return promise;
    }
    private SetProxy(): void {

        let self=this;
        this.proxy = new Proxy({}, {

            get: function(rcvr: any, name: PropertyKey)
            {
                // Для свойства нужно вернуть Promise
                if (name == "AllHello3")
                    return self.GetPromise(name, []);
                // А для Метода нужно вернуть функцию создающую Promise
                return (...args) => {
                   return self.GetPromise(name,args)
                };    
            }
        });
    }

    public async CallMethodAsync() {
        this.currentCount = await this.proxy.AllHello("Всем Привет");
    }

    public setResult(): void {

        let key: string;
        for (let name in this.dictionary) {
            key = name;
        }

        let item = <Item>this.dictionary[key];
        delete this.dictionary[key];
        item.resolve(item.value);
    }
}
```

И соответственно вызов

```
console.log('before async result ');
let res = await this.counter.proxy.AllHello1("Всем Привет");
console.log('Всем привет ' + res);
res = await this.counter.proxy.AllHello2();
console.log('func ' + res);
res = await this.counter.proxy.AllHello3;
console.log('property ' + res);
```

Comment: с точки зрения обращения getter это всегда свойство.

Comment: Ну это понятно, вопрос можно ли узнать, что свойство возвращает ссылку на метод?

Comment: Если это понятно, то почему вопрос не называется "как узнать что ссылка ведет на функцию?"

Comment: Я не знаю как сюда код вставить, поэтому дам ответ.

Comment: Спасибо подправлю

Comment: Зачем вам вообще свойства и поля? Чем принципиально `.AllHello3` в вашем понимании отличается от `.AllHello3()`?

Comment: Тем что в .Net классах есть поля,свойства, методы. Сейчас еще задам вопрос более развернутый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Proxy никак не может определить функцию вызывают, поле или свойство.

---

Если посмотреть в спецификации [алгоритм работы метода `get`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver) для Proxy, можно отметить, что если в конструкторе в объекте передаваемом во второй параметр отсутствует свойство `get` - идет просто попытка получить свойство целевого объект, по заданному имени.

Если свойство get указано - то просто выполняется соответствующая функция, которой:

1. `this` устанавливается как объект переданный вторым параметром в конструктор
2. первый параметр - target объект
3. второй параметр - имя метода
4. третий параметр - сам Proxy объект

Отсюда видно, что в момент вызова `get` - неизвестно как полученное свойство будет использоваться далее.

В случае в вопросе, когда `target` - фиктивный пустой объект, Proxy никак не может определить чем является запрашиваемое свойство, соответственно никак не может обработать различные ситуации: свойство, поле, функция.

Comment: Спасибо. Жалко. Можно все свойства вызывать как метод без параметров

Comment: Как это не может? А что мешает имея объект и имя получить ссылку и проверить к чему она ведет?

Comment: OlmerDale У меня объект это объект .Net . Для простоты это метод на Web сервисе. Можно конечно получить все свойства, возможно так и сделаю, но это несколько геморройно

Comment: @OlmerDale, то, что в вопросе объект пустой, и используется _только_ для создания Proxy. То есть в target объекте - вообще нет никаких свойств и автор вопроса хочет по способу вызова метода из Proxy определять что именно нужно вернуть

Comment: В этот раз даже не минусано, только за то что Вы смогли понять что  он хочет :)